# Compiz has no window decorations

Tags: debian, gui, compiz

I have installed Debian Minimal (bullseye, without gui). I want to install X11 and Compiz.
I installed `compiz`, `xinit`, `emerald`.
After that I've just created the ~/.xinitrc file with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
xterm &
exec compiz --replace
```

But when I start xorg (tried to replace the exec with: `compiz --replace`, `compiz --ccp`, `emerald --replace`, `compiz-decorator --replace`) I get no window decoration.

I also started `ccsm` and Window Decorations seems to be enabled.

What can I do?
No errors are shown.
Thanks!